# Running Horizon Failed - HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Tags: horizon

I installed Sitecore 9.3 and everything works fine, I didn't get any errors during installation.

I installed Horizon following the documentation.

I replaced all parameters from `parameters.ps1` file.

I run `install.ps1` and I didn't get any errors.

[image]

When I access the the Horizon Site I got the following error:

```
HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Common causes of this issue:
The application process failed to start
The application process started but then stopped
The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port

Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
```

Comment: Yes, I also faced same problem and solved after copied the licence file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I verify first time the logs folder of Horizon and it was empty.

I run in the root site of the site next command :

**dotnet Authoring.Host.dll** and I received next error :

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\horizonsc93sc.dev.local>dotnet Authoring.Host.dll

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: License file doesn't exist on disk.
   at Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Commands.SitecoreHostCommand.LoadLicenseXml(String filePath, String contentRootPath)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Commands.SitecoreHostCommand.OnExecuteAsync(CommandLineApplication app)
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.InvokeAsync(MethodInfo method, Object instance, Object[] arguments) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 77
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.OnExecute(ConventionContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 62
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Apply>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 25
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.<>c__DisplayClass126_0.<OnExecute>b__0() in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.cs:line 505
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute[TApp](CommandLineContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 31
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](CommandLineContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 145
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](IConsole console, String[] args) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 130
   at Sitecore.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Looks like the license wasn't copy it into the right folder.

**When I copy the license file into the folder: `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\horizonsc93sc.dev.local\sitecoreruntime\`
the Horizon editor start working.**

Comment: license is already in correct place but still I am getting error

Comment: did you restart the app_pool ?

Comment: Yes.. I tried that

Comment: I can see this error "Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/XXX' with physical root
 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXX\' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet .\Authoring.Host.dll',
 ErrorCode = '0x80070002 : 0." in application log

Comment: @SwatiGupta please take a look here also: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23211/horizon-http-error-502-5-process-failure/23223#23223 and my post here: https://www.flux-digital.com/blog/installing-sitecore-9-3-horizon/

Answer (score 0):

After copying the license file into the following folder resolved my issue :
When I copy the license file into the folder: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\horizonsc93sc.dev.local\sitecoreruntime\