# Horizon HTTP Error 502.5 Process Failure

Tags: horizon

I've installed Sitecore 9.3 and it is all working fine. I then installed Horizon and similarly to [this issue](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23209/running-horizon-failed) I am seeing a 502.5 error.

I have moved past the error mentioned in the above post by also copying the licence file to the /sitecoreruntime sub-folder in the Horizon application.

However I now get a different error instead, it looks like Horizon is trying to update my licence file but can't for some reason:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\horizon.93sc.dev.local>dotnet Authoring.Host.dll

Unhandled Exception: Sitecore.Framework.Configuration.Patcher.ConfigurationException: An error occurred during applying the patch file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\horizon.93sc.dev.local\Config\license.xml ---> System.Exception: Could not merge node 'signedlicense' in patch file 'license.xml'
   at Sitecore.Framework.Configuration.Patcher.XmlPatcher.ShouldPatchNode(XmlNode target, IXmlElement patch)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Configuration.Patcher.XmlPatcher.Merge(XmlNode target, IXmlElement patch)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Configuration.Patcher.XmlPatcher.ApplyPatch(String filename, XmlNode node)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Configuration.Patcher.ConfigReader.LoadIncludeFiles(IEnumerable`1 files, XmlNode node)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Framework.Configuration.Patcher.ConfigReader.LoadIncludeFiles(IEnumerable`1 files, XmlNode node)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Configuration.Patcher.ConfigReader.GetConfiguration(ISourceConfigFiles sitecoreRootConfiguration, Boolean includeNamespaces)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Configuration.SitecoreFileProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Configuration.SitecoreConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers, IConfigValueReader reader)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Configuration.SitecoreConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Configuration.SitecoreRuntimeConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Configuration.SitecoreConfiguration..ctor(ISitecorePluginManager pluginManager, ISitecoreHostingEnvironment hostEnvironment)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Hosting.ServiceExtensions.RunSitecore(IServiceProvider services, String[] args)
   at Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Commands.SitecoreHostCommand.OnExecuteAsync(CommandLineApplication app)
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.InvokeAsync(MethodInfo method, Object instance, Object[] arguments) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 77
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.OnExecute(ConventionContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 62
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Apply>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 25
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.<>c__DisplayClass126_0.<OnExecute>b__0() in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.cs:line 505
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute[TApp](CommandLineContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 31
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](CommandLineContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 145
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](IConsole console, String[] args) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 130
   at Sitecore.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

The error I see in my browser is as follows:

[image]

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: did you copy license.xml into config folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst the [other question I referenced](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23209/running-horizon-failed-http-error-502-5-process-failure) was a similar issue to this as it shows the same error in the browser (502.5) a different error is shown in the logs and a different solution is required.

To resolve this error I had to remove the licence that was not needed from `/config` (e.g: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\horizon.93sc.dev.local\Config`) as this was confusing Horizon.

> When I did this I had to do an `issreset` to make sure Horizon
>   correctly re-loaded the config and this error went away.

However to avoid this issue altogether it seems you  need to ensure you set the `$LicensePath` variable in the parameters.ps1 file to the Fullpath to the licence file, including the Filename when installing Horizon. e.g: `“C:\inetpub\wwwroot\93sc.dev.local\App_Data\license.xml”`

The official installation PDF isn’t clear about this.

You can read more about solving this error and other Horizon issues in  my blog post here: https://www.flux-digital.com/blog/installing-sitecore-9-3-horizon/

Thanks for Vlad Iobagiu for his help with this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, installation copied the license file to subfolder `\sitecoreruntime\App_Data` which was wrong.

When I ran `dotnet Authoring.Host.dll` from command line, I have received "License file doesn't exist on disk." error. I have just copied the license file from `\sitecoreruntime\App_Data` subfolder to parent `\sitecoreruntime\`. Then the app started to work

Answer (score 0):

Your error appear because license.xml was copy to the config folder, instead of SitecoreRuntime folder.

The **xml files** from the config folder are patched to your website configuration (to be honest I don't know how it works) and the **license.xml** can not be patched.

Comment: So the file that was copied to the wrong place (/config) was patched at install time and that is the one I should have copied to /SitecoreRuntime instead of the original licence file?

Comment: exactly, the license.xml should be inside sitecoreruntime folder.

Comment: I already did that but I get this other error. However I think I copied over the original licence file. So how do I go about patching it to fix this issue?